# Crash python when i use (0) in my codes as num1 for equation

Tags: python, helper, equation

```
import cmath
import math


print(" we are going to programming second grade equation in python")
print(" a^2 x + b x + c =0")

num1 = int(input(" enter A please : "))
num2 = int(input(" enter B please : "))
num3 = int(input(" enter c please : "))

v = num2*num2 - 4 *num1 * num3

if v < 0:
    print("wrong values")

else:
    print("root of delta =", v)
    k= math.sqrt(v)

def two_sol(x,y) :
    x_f= (-y + v)/(4*x)
    x_s =(-y - v)/(4*x)

    return x_f , x_s

def one_sol(x):
    x_f = (-y + v) / (4 * x)

if v >0 :
    print("we have two solution :" ,two_sol(num1,num2)) 

elif v == 0:
   print( "we have one solution :" , one_sol(y))

else:
    print(" there is no solution !!")
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Application closes

Comment: There's no output at all? No error message? None of your calls to `print` run? Nothing happens at all?

Comment: If you put 0 as num1 aka x aka a, you will get a RuntimeError because you divide by zero

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you have a division by zero error: num1 -> x

```
def two_sol(x,y) :
    x_f= (-y + v)/(4*x)
    x_s =(-y - v)/(4*x)
```

and

```
def one_sol(x):
    x_f = (-y + v) / (4 * x)
```

You need to check whether x is zero. If x is zero, there should be only one solution.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because we can't divide any number by 0, so what you wan't to do?
if you want, when x input is take 0 it replaced by 1 that means number is divided by 1, the code will be,

```
def two_sol(x,y) :
    if int(x) == 0: x = 1 
    x_f= (-y + v)/(4*x)
    x_s =(-y - v)/(4*x)

    return x_f , x_s

def one_sol(x):
     if int(x) == 0: x = 1 
     x_f = (-y + v) / (4 * x)
```

else if you want, when x input is take 0 it return and don't calculate any more! the code will be,

```
    def two_sol(x,y) :
    if int(x) == 0: return 
    x_f= (-y + v)/(4*x)
    x_s =(-y - v)/(4*x)

    return x_f , x_s

def one_sol(x):
     if int(x) == 0: return 
     x_f = (-y + v) / (4 * x)
```